# Thread are not happening at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a program that fetches data via an API. I created a function that only takes the target data as an argument and with a `for-loop` I run this method 10 times.

The programm takes quite some time to display the data because the next function call only happens when the function before has done its work.

I want to use Threads to make it all happen quicker. However, I'm confused. On realpython.org I read this:

*A thread is a separate flow of execution. **This means that your program will have two things happening at once.** But for most Python 3 implementations the different threads do not actually execute at the same time: they merely appear to. It’s tempting to think of threading as having two (or more) different processors running on your program, each one doing an independent task at the same time. That’s almost right. The threads may be running on different processors, **but they will only be running one at a time**.*

First they say: "This means that your program will have two things happening at once" and then they say "but they will only be running one at a time". So my threads are not done simultaneously?

I want to make a decision on whether to use Threads or Multiprocessing but I can't figure it out.

Can somebody help?

Comment: One way to think of it is that the activity on multiple threads gets interleaved.  "Two things happening at once" means that you can't write your program with the assumption that one function will execute in its entirety on one thread, and then the other will execute in its entirety on another -- you might get a couple of lines into thread 1's function, and then execute a line in thread 2's function, and then switch back, etc.

Comment: If all you want is for your GUI to be responsive during a long-running operation then threading is fine. Multiprocessing is (generally) there if you want to use concurrency to make something run faster. I would recommend threading for you, since it is slightly easier to use.

Comment: @Oli Actually I want to fetch cryptocurrency prices in real time and make buy and/or sell orders for different types of crypto. So if I want to do it for every crypto independently, shall I use Threading or Multiprocessing?

Comment: @newbypyth It sounds to me like the biggest performance bottleneck to your program would be network speed, not CPU speed, so I would recommend threading.

Comment: @Oli The bottleneck is not so much the PC but that I might lose trading opportunities when I wait for the calculations for one crypto to be finished before the other calculations start. Lets say the calculations for crypto one finish and no opportunity to buy or sell was found. Now I do a few other calculations before we start over again at crypto 1. If in the meanwhile there was a possibility, I have missed it.

Comment: The calculations are (probably) performed almost instantaneuosly, compared to the wait times in receiving the data over the network. However, if you run everything in a single loop you will still need to sit trhough all the waiting time. However, running in different threads, you do not have to wait for one calculation to be finished before next can start. Generally in IO bound communcation (such as retrieving data from the Internet) threading is what you want, rather than multiprocessing.

Comment: And can I prevent Python from outputting everything immediately? I would need to buffer everything and then print the output when calculations for one loop are done. Otherwise it will just mix up everything from every function whenever it finds a `print()`-statement.

Comment: @newbypyth You can have a single thread that does all the printing, and other threads fetch data and do calculations, sending results to the printing thread via a queue (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). The printing thread can decide what to do with these results, like waiting until enough data is collected before printing everything.

Answer (score 1):

With both Threads or Multiprocessing you must assume that execution of your program could jump from one thread/process to another randomly. The difference is that with Threads, code is never really executed at the same time. That means there is always only one CPU core doing your work. With Multiprocessing, your code runs on multiple cores at the same time. So only Multiprocessing will solve your computation N times faster with N processes. (There will be some overhead of course.) If you are not doing any heavy computation, but need to create the illusion of things running in parallel, use threads. This is especially useful for GUIs.

The confusing part is that **IO** (copying files or loading something from the web for example) **is not CPU bound**, as it does not require a lot of CPU instructions to happen. So always use threads for this. To understand it a bit more, you should realise that when a thread is waiting for an IO operation to finish, it is actually in a blocked state. This allows other threads to run. So if you use threads to fetch data the first thread will start loading it and then block. This makes room for the the second thread to do the same and so on. When one of the threads has the data ready, it will unblock, run the rest of its code and finish.
(Note that when multiple threads are running they can pause randomly and give room for other threads to run for a while and then carry on. (See first sentence of this answer.))

Generally always use threads unless you need to do something CPU heavy in parallel. Multiprocessing has a lot of limitations when it comes to how it works internally and using it is more complicated and heavy.

This only applies to some implementations of Python tough, for example the most commonly used "official" implementation, CPython. In other languages or less common Python implementations threads are often able to execute instructions on multiple cores at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! I want to do Crypto Trading with Python. I have set my program to do calculations for 6 different cryptos. In an endless `while-loop`, the calculations are made for crypto 1, then crypto 2, ..., crypto 6. When crypto 6 is done, the programm starts again with crypto 1. Lets say the program is at crtypto 3 and the crypto 1 course is so good that I would like to buy then my programm wont do that because it currently does calculations for crypto 3, then crypto 4, ... and so on. Now when I come back to crypto 1 because everything else is done, the opportunity is missed. What do I do?

Comment: This is a bit too simplified. There is nothing that inherently prevents threads from running on different cores, I think. However, the global interpreter lock, the GIL, prevents any two threads to run at the same time. Thus, there is little to no use for the OS to schedule the threads on different cores. However, when calling a library written in C, e.g. `numpy`-functions, these are not stopped by the GIL, and could thus run in parallel.

Comment: @JohanL You are right that it is implementation dependent, I will add it to my answer. Calling native code does releases the GIL, but I think this is a bit out of scope of the question.

Comment: @newbypyth Couldn't you just have 6 threads, each one of them handling one currency?

Comment: @fikusekk Yes that would be the best I think but I need to find a way to buffer the output so the output is only send when the end of ther function is reached. Otherwise it is all mixed up and a big mess.